# A-Frame. How to include a form in VR scene?

Tags: aframe, webvr

does anyone know how to include a form in the VR scene built with A-Frame? Any experience with Web2VR?

Answer (score 1):

If by a form you mean a standard HTML 2d form then you can simply overlay the 3d scene with any standard HTML element. Just use the `z-index` parameter.

#### Example

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.2.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
</head>

<body>
  <a-scene>
    <a-sphere position="0 2 -10"color="red"></a-sphere>
    <a-plane color="green" position="0 0 -5" rotation="-90 0 0" width="20" height="20"></a-plane>
    <a-sky color="#aaf"></a-sky>
  </a-scene>
  <div>
    <form style="z-index: 100; position: absolute; left: 10px; top: 10px">
      <input type="text"/><br/>
      <input type="number"/><br/>
      <input type="date"/><br/>
      <input type="submit"/>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

You can also use an `embedded` attribute on `a-scene` to specify where the scene should be placed inside the standard web page.

#### Example

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.2.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
</head>

<body>
  <a-scene embedded style="width: 200px; height: 100px">
    <a-sphere position="0 2 -10"color="red"></a-sphere>
    <a-plane color="green" position="0 0 -5" rotation="-90 0 0" width="20" height="20"></a-plane>
    <a-sky color="#aaf"></a-sky>
  </a-scene>
  <div>
    <form>
      <input type="text"/><br/>
      <input type="number"/><br/>
      <input type="date"/><br/>
      <input type="submit"/>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer